# Are quadrilinear weak boson couplings possible?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction

$ZZ\rightarrow ZZ$, $ZZ\rightarrow W^+ W^-$, etc.

Are these interactions possible?

Comment: Yes. See, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0537  , fig.10

Comment: They're not just possible. They're unavoidable by gauge invariance in the presence of the kinetic terms $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ for the gauge fields.

Comment: Ahemm... not so fast. the second one is, of course, but a 4-*Z* tree coupling is not present in the tree gauge lagrangian: basically there is no nonvanishing trace of a product of two commutators *only* involving $\tau_3$s.

Comment: ...But you could get a tree 4-*Z* coupling by exchange of a Higgs, from the Higgs part of the lagrangian.